# Custom compound rows in NSPredicateEditor

Tags: core-data, nspredicateeditor

Say we have two Core Data entities:

- entity **Bar**

  - attribute **bar1**;
  - attribute **bar2**;
- entity **Foo**

  - attribute **foo1**;
  - attribute **foo2**;
  - to-many relationship <Bar*> **bars**

I want to use NSPredicateEditor to search for "any Foos that have bars with (bar1='term1' and bar2='term2')". That is, multiple matches in the *same* Bar.

With some kind of custom compound predicate that has a UI like this

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

I know how to create top-level NSPredicateEditorRowTemplates to search for Foos based on Bar attributes (Foo.bars.bar1).
But those are compounded along with the Foo attribute subpredicates, so I can't limit the search to multiple attributes in the same Bar.

When selecting Bar attributes to search, the list should limit itself to the Bar attributes.

Is it even possible to have multiple types of compound predicates in the same NSPredicateEditor?

Surprisingly little code for customizing NSPredicateEditor out there...

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Hitesh!

Comment: You can't combine simple rows (foo1) and compound rows (bars contain item). It might be possible to add compound row templates (any/all/no bars match the following) but it seems impossible to have foo rows and bar rows.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to match key paths (bars.bar1) in the same way as simple keys (foo1). These criteria are also groupable into compound predicates. But the subpredicates of such a compound predicate will always operate on *all* bars. I haven't found a way to match criteria in the same object (bar1='term1' and bar2='term2'). - So are multiple compound predicate types not possible? They don't necessarily have to show up in popup button. NSRuleEditor has a method insertRowAtIndex:withType:asSubrowOfRow:animate:, which looks promising, but the type of NSPredicateEditorRowTemplates is private.

Comment: The type is a `NSRuleEditorRowType`: `NSRuleEditorRowTypeSimple` or `NSRuleEditorRowTypeCompound`. It is not possible to change the type of a row or to limit the attribute popup to Foo properties in some rows and to Bar properties in other rows. Take a look at the comments in NSRuleEditor.h, it explains how `NSRuleEditor` works. `NSPredicateEditor` creates the two trees of criteria from the row templates.

Comment: Thanks. Much better documentation in the header than online. It may not be too difficult to subclass NSRuleEditor.